# CentOS 6.5 Dependency errors while installing hhvm

Tags: linux, repository, dependencies, centos6.5

I am trying to install hhvm on newly created droplet. For this, I am following [this guide](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Centos-6.5).

After adding the Gleez repository, I tried running

```
yum update && yum upgrade
```

Lots of lines, and then at the end:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: less-436-13.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: nginx-1.7.9-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (@nginx)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: grep-2.6.3-6.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But it gave me lots of error.

I want to understand why this kind of error happens and what is workaround?

Since today I have been ignoring these types of errors and when they appear, I used to uninstall specific packages or start again from scratch.

---

**UPDATE1:**

i tried doing

```
yum clean all
```

still its showing errors, e.g.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: less-436-13.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: nginx-1.7.9-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (@nginx)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: grep-2.6.3-6.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.33-2.el6.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-9.el6.x86_64 (gleez)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Removing: libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64 (@base)
               libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libicu51_2-51.2-9.2.x86_64 (gleez)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

Your local yum cache appears to be out of date. Run `yum clean all` and then try again.

Or it could be that the repository is broken. In that case you'll need to contact the repository maintainer.

Comment: did yum clean all, and its still showing the errors. is there way i can remove updates installed by specific repo ?

Comment: Was anything installed by that repo? It doesn't seem to have any actual packages in it.

Comment: no. just added that repo and tried to update .